How to Implement Drag-and-Drop Functionality for Images in React Native?
I'm working on a React Native app where I need to implement drag-and-drop functionality for images. Specifically, I want users to be able to rearrange the order of images by dragging and dropping them within a container.
I've searched for tutorials and libraries, but I haven't found a clear solution for implementing this in a React Native app. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve drag-and-drop functionality for images in React Native?
Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that:

Allows users to drag and drop images within a container.
Provides smooth and responsive dragging behavior.
Is compatible with React Native components, such as <Image />.

Any advice, code examples, or recommended libraries would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
